# Pandas using row labels in boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

      a         b         c
0  1.877317  0.109646  1.634978
1 -0.048044 -0.837403 -2.198505
2 -0.708137  2.342530  1.053073
3 -0.547951 -1.790304 -2.159123
4  0.214583 -0.856150 -0.477844
5  0.159601 -1.705155  0.963673
```

We can boolean index it like this

```
df[df.a > 0]

     a         b         c
0  1.877317  0.109646  1.634978
4  0.214583 -0.856150 -0.477844
5  0.159601 -1.705155  0.963673
```

We can also slice it via row labels like this:

```
df.ix[[0,2,4]]

    a         b         c
0  1.877317  0.109646  1.634978
2 -0.708137  2.342530  1.053073
4  0.214583 -0.856150 -0.477844
```

I would like to do both these operations at the same time (So I avoid making an unnecessary copy just to do the row label filter). How would I go about doing it?

Pseudo code for what I am looking for:

```
df[(df.a > 0) & (df.__index__.isin([0,2,4]))]
```

Comment: You can try with `df.ix[df['a'] > 0, [0,2,4]]`

Comment: For the above example data frame that would throw an exception, since this is trying to pull the 0, 2nd and 4th columns, and we only have 3 columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You nearly had it:

```
In [11]: df[(df.a > 0) & (df.index.isin([0, 2, 4]))]
Out[11]: 
          a         b         c
0  1.877317  0.109646  1.634978
4  0.214583 -0.856150 -0.477844
```

Comment: Indeed! Almost! Right there!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[functools.reduce(lambda x, y : x & y, [df.a>0, df.index.isin([0, 2, 4])])]
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer; Provide an explanation to what's hapenning in here.