# Using a MultiIndex value in a boolean selection (while setting)

Tags: pandas

There is a similar question here:  [Pandas using row labels in boolean indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725068/pandas-using-row-labels-in-boolean-indexing)

But that one uses a simple index and I can't figure out how to generalize it to a MultiIndex:

```
df = DataFrame( { 'ssn' : [  489,  489,  220,  220 ],
                  'year': [ 2009, 2010, 2009, 2010 ],
                  'tax' : [  300,  600,  800,  900 ],    
                  'flag': [    0,    0,    0,    0 ] } )

df.set_index( ['ssn','year'], inplace=True )
```

Semi-solutions:

`df.flag[ (df.year ==2010) & (df.tax<700) ] = 9`  (works if drop=False in set_index)

`df.flag[ (df.index==2010) & (df.tax<700) ] = 9`  (works for a simple index)

I've tried several things but I just can't figure out how to generalize from simple index to multi.  E.g. df.index.year=2010 and 20 other guesses...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `index.get_level_values()`, e.g.

```
df.flag[(df.index.get_level_values('year') == 2010) & (df.tax < 700)] = 9
```

Comment: to not use chain indexing (always a good idea!), do this: ``df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('year') == 2010) & (df.tax < 700),'flag'] = 9``. In 0.15.0/master, this will work: ``df.loc[df.index.isin([2010],level='year') & (df.tax<700),'flag'] = 9``

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'm still trying to understand the chain indexing thing.